# iframe contents stuck if browser goes to new URL and comes back (via back button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser-history

I am using a jquery  iframe plugin to display new contents on same page. It works good. But If I go to a new URL in the parent window and use BACK button to come back, then all iframe links load the last opened iframe url before parent window went to the new url.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using an older version of prettyphoto that doesn't update hash in url. Current version does , look on main plugin demos. The hash allows for bookmarking and history support and the plugin should read the hash and open appropriate gallery when page loads

Example of hash update in address bar when clicking a demo:

`#prettyPhoto[pp_gal2]/3/`

Comment: depends on iframe source...if it is cross domain you can't access contents with script

Comment: look at `contents()` method. API has some iframe examples http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: prettyphoto API isn't as robust as some others like colorbox that give you access to more callbacks such as before open. You would likely need to modify the plugin a bit